# error: video system not initialized; Is there a solution?

Tags: python, pygame

I have looked and looked. Every I find this question asked, the person is told to call pygame.init()
When the asker says that they have done that, there are no more replies.
I've tried everything I can think of and nothing works.

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python26\TwC\main.py", line 183, in 
   for e in pygame.event.get():
error: video system not initialized

My imports in case there's a conflict:

```
#imports
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
```

Here's where I'm calling pygame.init(), just to show that I am:

```
#initialize
os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

#setup display
pygame.display.set_caption("TwC V%s" % version)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 240))
```

And lastly, here's the area of the line that raises the error:

```
while running:

    clock.tick(60)

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
```

EDIT:
Removing the section of code causing the error just causes the same error to be caused by another section, so that means issue is with pygame.init()
I'm thinking of just scrapping the whole thing and redoing it. It didn't take long to do.

Comment: Does the code work if you don't have an event queue in place?  Does a window pop up that is 320x240 if you run the program with the event-handling for-loop commented out?

Comment: Nope. pygame.init() seems to be the actual problem.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\TwC\main.py", line 126, in <module>
    class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  File "C:\Python26\TwC\main.py", line 133, in Block
    (32,0,16,16)])  #grass - 3
  File "C:\Python26\TwC\main.py", line 59, in imgsat
    imgs.append(self.imgat(rect, colorkey))
  File "C:\Python26\TwC\main.py", line 49, in imgat
    img = pygame.Surface(rect.size).convert()
error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized

Comment: How are you running the program. Form hte traceback, I can see you are running windows. Does Pygame (witha display) works from the idle shell? Have you tried setting it up from the DOS shell? Have you tried saving the file as a .pyw, instead of .py?

Answer (score 1):

Can you run this boilerplate successfully ? [Pygame, simple physics engine, how to hold points between planes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677890/pygame-simple-physics-engine-how-to-hold-points-between-planes/5799588#5799588)

Answer (score 1):

The very simple fix is to insure that the very last line of code in your program `pygame.quit()` is not indented.  Errors will make it seem to be earlier lines in your code....fooled me a for about 15 minutes.